# Scala Option's collect method doesn't like my PartialFunction

Tags: scala, collect, scala-option, partialfunction

I think I'm missing something:

```
scala> Some(1) collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> None collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})   
<console>:6: error: value > is not a member of Nothing
       None collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
                                 ^
<console>:6: error: value + is not a member of Nothing
       None collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
```

Why is this error happening? I think I'm misunderstanding how `collect` works...

Comment: BTW, you don't need the parens around the curly braces: `Some(1) collect { case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0}` should work as well.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. Each of us has their own style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you specify, the literal `None` is of type `Option[Nothing]`.  This is necessary, since None has to be a valid member of all types Option[_].  If you instead wrote

```
(None:Option[Int]) collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
```

or

```
val x:Option[Int] = None
x collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
```

then the compiler would be able to type check your collect call

Comment: From this line execution `(None:Option[Int]) collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0}) ` can you explain why we still get `None` instead of `0`?

Comment: I would prefer `Option.empty[Int]` over `(None:Option[Int])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
None collect ({ case n if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
```

Why would `n` have the method `>`? There's nothing in there to allow the compiler to assume that. So, try changing that to:

```
None collect ({ case n: Int if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0})
```

And you'll get the following error message:

```
<console>:8: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Int
 required: Nothing
       None collect ({ case n: Int if n > 0 => n + 1; case _ => 0}) 
                               ^
```

Meaning, basically, that the compiler knows an `Int` is impossible here, since you are just passing `None`. As it happens, `None` is of type `Option[Nothing]`.